# ping: cannot resolve d2.local: Unknown host

Tags: python, bash, ssh, raspberry-pi, ping

I am trying to access the setup pi's hostname, this is the tutorial I am using: https://docs.donkeycar.com/guide/install_software/

I am creating something which can be used to login to wifi on first boot.

This is done with first creating:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="<your network name>"
psk="<your password>"

}
```

Then I run the command: `ping d2.local`to try to get the pi's hostname.

It is returning this error: ping: `cannot resolve d2.local: Unknown host`

It seems like it is not able to find this file, but I am not exactly sure why.

Additionally, I have googled the web for hours searching for an answer and have not come across anything. Any guidance, advice, or help would be appreciated.

Comment: **Unknown host**: it's not the file but the host that is unknown. does the pi run on network? his hostname is d2?   
I do not see a question about programming...

Comment: The answer is in the message `cannot resolve d2.local`. the host  d2.local is not known in DNS and not in `/etc/hosts`, so `ping` cannot resolve the hostname to an IP address. You're better of searching raspberrypi.stackexchange.com for a wifi set-up.